# What is causing An internal build error has occured. Uncaught Exception in Compiler?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I'm getting this error in my project and I don't know how to fix it, I haven't seen it before:

> java.lang.NullPointerException at macromedia.asc.semantics.ConstantEvaluator.PreprocessDefinitionTypeInfo(ConstantEvaluator.java:3265) at flex2.compiler.as3.As3Compiler.analyze3(As3Compiler.java:701) 1131: Classes must not be nested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was caused by a syntax error below:

```
public function addDecorator( decorator:IDecorator, subDrawLayer:Sprite ) : void {

    if (subDrawLayer==null) {
        subDrawLayer:Sprite = new Sprite();
    }

    drawLayer.addChild(subDrawLayer);

    decorators.push(decorator);
    subDrawLayers[decorator] = subDrawLayer;
}
```

It is specifically this line, `subDrawLayer:Sprite = new Sprite();`
The subDrawLayer variable type is accidentally defined twice; once in the parameters and then once inline in the function. It should be `subDrawLayer = new Sprite();`